# Why Object is returning random values in perl

Tags: perl

I am new in OO perl, below is the code i have written for my learning purpose but unfortunately i am not getting correct output :

**#Calculation.pm**

```
package Calculation;

sub new
{
  my $class =shift;
 # my $number =shift; 
  my $self ={};
  bless ($self,$class);
  return $self;
}

sub add
{
 my $val_01=shift;
 my $val_02=shift;
 my $total =  $val_01+$val_02;
  return($total);

}

1;
```

**#Test.pl**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 

use warnings;
use strict; 
use Calculation;
my $obj = Calculation->new();

my $result =$obj->add(1,2);
print"$result\n";
```

$result is returning a random values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As has been pointed out, you aren't taking account of the first parameter that is passed implicitly to the method call, usually assigned to `$self`.

You can also omit some of the intermediate variables to simplifiy, and it is common practice to omit the `return` statement when the value to be returned is the last statement in the subroutine.

This variant of your code works fine

**Calculation.pm**

```
use strict;
use warnings;

package Calculation;

sub new {
  my $class = shift;
  bless {}, $class;
}

sub add {
  my $self = shift;
  my ($val_01, $val_02) = @_;
  $val_01 + $val_02;
}

1;
```

**Test.pl**

```
use strict; 
use warnings;

use Calculation;

my $obj = Calculation->new;

my $result = $obj->add(1, 2);

print "$result\n";
```

**output**

```
3
```

Answer (score 6):

When you call `$obj->add(1,2)` your `add` sub gets 3 arguments: `$obj, 1, 2`. You're shifting and adding the first 2 arguments, `$obj` and `1`. When `$obj` is converted to a number for addition, its memory address is used. Add 1 to that and you get a not-quite-random-but-certainly-ugly number.

You just need to add another shift at the top of `sub add`.