# perl: getting a value from a function of the object

Tags: perl, function

So I have a class AClass with variables (x, y), and a function which should take two objects as arguments of the same class, compute their x and y, and return a new instance of the class with computed values.

```
package AClass;

sub new {
    my $class = shift;
    my $x = shift;
    my $y = shift;
    my $self  = { 
        x => $x,
        y => $y
    };
    return bless($self, $class);    
}

sub getX {
    my $self = shift;
    return $self->{'x'};
}

sub getY {
    my $self = shift;
    return $self->{'y'};
}

sub addition {
    my ($c1, $c2) = @_;

    return new AClass(
        $c1->getX() + $c1->getX(), 
        $c1->getY() + $c2->getY() 
    );
}


my $a1 = AClass->new(6, 4);
my $a2 = AClass->new(4, 3);

my $val = AClass::addition(\$v1, \$v2);
say $val.getX();
```

I'm getting error "Can't call method "getX" on unblessed reference". I think the problem is in addition function, when I'm trying to access the values of the objects which are not the real numbers or ?

Comment: Read the first answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22665135/why-object-is-returning-random-values-in-perl).

Comment: Please write your `new AClass(...)` as `AClass->new(...)`. You will save yourself a lot of pain at some point in the future if you get used to writing it like that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a number of problems here.

- You are using `$v1` and `$v2` when presumably you mean `$a1` and `$a2`
- You are passing *references* to those objects, instead of the objects themselves
- Your `addition` method adds the X value of `$c1` to itself instead of to the `X` value of `$c2`
- You are using the string concatenation operator `.` instead of the indirection operator `->`
- It is best to use lower-case letters for lexical identifiers. Capitals are generally reserved for globals like package names

You must *always* `use strict` and `use warnings` at the top of your program. In this case you would have been alerted to the fact that `$v1` and `$v2` hadn't been declared.

This version of your code works fine

```
use strict;
use warnings;

package AClass;

sub new {
  my $class = shift;
  my ($x, $y) = @_;
  bless { x => $x, y => $y }, $class;
}

sub get_x {
  my $self = shift;
  $self->{x};
}

sub get_y {
  my $self = shift;
  $self->{y};
}

sub addition {
  my ($c1, $c2) = @_;
  AClass->new(
      $c1->get_x + $c2->get_x,
      $c1->get_y + $c2->get_y
  );
}

package main;

use feature 'say';

my $a1 = AClass->new(6, 4);
my $a2 = AClass->new(4, 3);

my $val = AClass::addition($a1, $a2);
say $val->get_x;
```

**output**

```
10
```

Comment: @ikegami: Perhaps. But I take the view that a Perl object is a blessed reference, not the underlying data item. In any case I can't find a way to rewrite it so that talking about *references to references* isn't more confusing!

Answer (score 3):

You use `$v1` instead `$a1`. Always use `use strict; use warnings;`.

Also, you're taking a reference for no reason.

```
my $val = AClass::addition($a1, $a2);
```

The following would also work (though `add`) would be a better word:

```
my $val = $a1->addition($a2);
```